# UISearch with tamil keys in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have seen many code about searching a content, none of them not help. My situtation is, i have loaded a `UITableView` with tamil contents. Now i need to search with tamil keys & how to filter a tamil text.

In ios7 apple has announced tamil keyboard. Please suggest me or give me link to resolve this problem. I know how to do search english contents in `UITableView`.

THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Answer (score 0):

Bacially You need tamil contects to match with the tamil word

```
 NSString *strTamil = @"ஹலோ";
    NSString *strEnglish = @"Hello";
    if([strTamil isEqualToString:@"ஹலோ"]){
        NSLog(@"Match");
    }

    if([strEnglish isEqualToString:@"ஹலோ"]){
        NSLog(@"Match");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"No Match");

    }
```

Comment: how to do this in uiserachbar.how to check the all contents,If i type ஹ in keyboard

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view  follow this tutorial